# Как сделать так, чтобы текст UI был на заднем плане и не перекрывал игровые объекты в Unity 2D?

Tags: c#, ui, unity3d

Делаю игру наподобие Don`t Touch the Spikes, по центру выводится сколько собрано ключей. Хочу чтоб этот текст не перекрывал игровые объекты. Пробовал менять Sort Order, не помогло.

Comment: Попробуйте поменять Z позицию.

Answer (score 2):

Изначально у `Canvas` тип `Screen Space-Overlay` и он рендерится отдельно по своим правилам и накладывается поверх камеры. Для надписей внутри сцены создай отдельный `Canvas` с типом `World Space` и задовай `Text` и другим `UI`, мировые координаты в `Update`.

Comment: Они тогда кривые и сжатые.